# How to get position and deduct of hand finger on Image in PHP

Tags: php

I have one image [image]

I need to deduct finger position according that position I can add or set ring in that finger.

Please let let me know how do this in PHP.

I try to something little bit get image center and add some text but I think not relevant for my requirment.

```
$hand_img = "hand.jpg";
$image_dir = "uploads/";
$font_size = 20;
$angle = 90;
$font = dirname(__FILE__) . '/fonts/ARIAL.TTF';    
$text = "Abid";
$color = 000;

//list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image_dir.$hand_img);

$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_dir.$hand_img);
//list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($jpg_image);

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($attr);die;

// Get image dimensions
//$width = imagesx($jpg_image);
//$height = imagesy($jpg_image);
// Get center coordinates of image
$centerX = $width / 2;
$centerY = $height / 2;
// Get size of text
list($left, $bottom, $right, , , $top) = imageftbbox($font_size, $angle, $font, $text);
// Determine offset of text
$left_offset = ($right - $left) / 2;
$top_offset = ($bottom - $top) / 2;
// Generate coordinates
$x = $centerX - $left_offset;
$y = $centerY - $top_offset;
// Add text to image
imagettftext($image_dir.$hand_img, $font_size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
```

Comment: Is the code at all relevant to your problem?

Comment: I think no I just try out

Comment: Hand image will change everytime ? if not you can place the ring image using the static x and y axis.

Comment: Hand image upload by user so every time it's changed